# How to configure 2 MDBs in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jms, weblogic11g

My code is deployed in weblogic 11g, I have already configured 1 MDB using spring. 
It is deployed and working fine. I have created a JMS server in weblogic and the queue details are in that server . I have only 1 sub deployment for this JMS server. I created another MDB the same way i created the 1st one , but this has different connection factory and destination factory. I configured this in to the same JMS server which was already there. But the issue is , only 1 MDB is working at a time . THe ont MDB meaning , the MDB which i created the 2nd time.

Please advice me on how to create 2 MDBs using Spring , both should work at a time.

Comment: Please post code on how you are setting up your Spring message listeners and the configuration you have used to configure them.

Comment: http://zachxu.blogspot.in/2010/03/create-weblogic-jms-foreign-server-and.html

I have used the exact code.

Comment: Are you using an old version of Spring? That blog post is eight years old. Why don't you use the contemporary Spring technique here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/
Again, without more code examples, it's going to be hard for people to help you here.